# Using itertools in python 3.5, how do I create only some variations of some lists, but all variations of others?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Right now I'm using `itertools` to create thousands of variations of meta descriptions for a website. The sentence structure goes like this:

(`SentencePart1a`|`SentencePart1b`) `Keyword1`, `Keyword2`, and `Keyword3`. (`MiddleSentenceA`|`MiddleSentenceB`). (`FinalSentenceA`|`FinalSentenceB`).

The short version of the script:

```
import itertools
metas = [
['Shop our store for ', 'Browse our shop for ,'], #SentenceParts
['keyword,', 'keyword,', 'etc,'],
['keyword, and', 'keyword, and', 'etc, and'], 
['keyword.', 'keyword.', 'etc.'], 
['Sentence about our store.', 'A different sentence about our store.'], #MiddleSentences
['A final sentence about our store.', 'A different final sentence about our store.'] #FinalSentences
    ]
variantmetas = list(itertools.product(*metas))
#print (variantmetas)
for s in variantmetas:
print(' '.join(s))
```

Right now I get every variation of all of these things. My program spits out all sentence parts, all middle sentences, and all final sentences even if Keywords 1-3 are the same.

**How do I make it so that keywords 1-3 only show up one time and with one random variation of Sentence parts? In other words: all variations of the keywords only once, with one `SentencePart`, one `MiddleSentence`, and one `FinalSentence`.**

I am trying to minimize redundancy in the final list.

Answer (score 1):

Just perform the product on the keywords, not on the sentences.

Use `random.choice` on the start & end sentences, and generate the result using a list comprehension.

Proposal without any reorganization of the `metas` list, which may be better to isolate the keywords, from the start/end sentences:

```
import itertools,random
metas = [
['Shop our store for ', 'Browse our shop for ,'], #SentenceParts
['keyword,', 'keyword,', 'etc,'],
['keyword, and', 'keyword, and', 'etc, and'],
['keyword.', 'keyword.', 'etc.'],
['Sentence about our store.', 'A different sentence about our store.'], #MiddleSentences
['A final sentence about our store.', 'A different final sentence about our store.'] #FinalSentences
    ]
variantmetas = [[random.choice(metas[0])]+list(l)+[random.choice(metas[-2]),random.choice(metas[-1])] for l in itertools.product(*metas[1:-2])]
for s in variantmetas:
    print(' '.join(s))
```

extract of the result:

```
Shop our store for  etc, keyword, and keyword. Sentence about our store. A different final sentence about our store.
Browse our shop for , etc, keyword, and etc. Sentence about our store. A different final sentence about our store.
Browse our shop for , etc, etc, and keyword. Sentence about our store. A final sentence about our store.
Shop our store for  etc, etc, and keyword. Sentence about our store. A different final sentence about our store.
Shop our store for  etc, etc, and etc. Sentence about our store. A final sentence about our store.
```